# Wix Bootstrapper with large package

Tags: wix, burn, wix3.11

I am using Wix Toolset 3.11 and am attempting to create a Wix bootstrapper that is installing a very large prerequisite to my software - a legacy InstallShield executable with ~5000 associated files found in ~600 folders. I have compressed all these files into a single self-extracting archive that is approximately 3GB. I am getting the following error when attempting to build:

> light.exe(0,0): error LGHT0001: Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.

Here is my current relevant XML in the bootstrapper:

```xml
<Chain>
   <PackageGroupRef Id="MyPrerequisites"/>
   <PackageGroupRef Id="ReallyBigExe"/>
   <PackageGroupRef Id="OtherStuff"/>
</Chain>
<Fragment>
   <util:RegistrySearch Id=ReallyBigExeFound" Key="Assume searching stuff is here"/>
   <PackageGroup Id=ReallyBigExe">
      <ExePackage InstallCondition="ReallyBigExeFound"
                  Compressed="no" 
                  DisplayName="Install Really Big Thing"
                  Permanent="no"
                  SourceFile="Packages\ReallyBigThing.exe"
                  Name="ReallyBigThing.exe"/>
   </PackageGroup>
</Fragment>
```

I've tried different variants of compressed, cached, name, etc and all result in the same error. I'm aware that this is due to the large file size of the included exe; see the [Github Issue here](https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/4008/).

I've also seen that detached containers are supposed to help with this issue. I have tried several combinations of using the container with my PackageGroup, also to no avail.

So, the question: How do I include this really big exe package with my installer in a way that lets me install it in the package chain, but does not embed it in the bootstrap data files?

Comment: I am not up to speed on bootstrappers, but what format is the prereq? Is it an MSI file wrapped in that EXE? If so, how do you compile it? Could you perhaps compile it with external cab files? You could use 2 external cab files to allow each to be under 2GB? I have not used it, but several developers recommend the [dotnetinstaller bootstrapper](http://dblock.github.io/dotnetinstaller/). Just a suggestion off the top of my head since it looks like you might not have luck with Burn.

Comment: The prerequisite is a collection of cab files and executable files that have been compressed into a single self-extracting archive. It's a legacy InstallShield installer with ~5000 payload files contained in ~600 payload folders.

I would try dotnetinstaller, but using Wix is also one of the requirements for the project.

Comment: Alternatively, try replacing the single big archive with generating payload elements for the 5000 files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My resolution to the problem:

We did not want to track the files of the external "ReallyBigExe" as it is supposed to be a standalone product. Rather than packing the 5k files into a payload in the installer, I created a utility that allows executing an arbitrary executable:

```cs
static int Main(string[] args)
{
  // Check your arguments here

  string path = args[0];
  string executable = args[1];
  path = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
  path = Path.Combine(path, executable);

  try
  {
    if(!File.Exists(path)) throw new FileNotFoundException();
    Process p = new Process()
    {
      StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(path)
    };
    p.Start();
    p.WaitForExit();
  }
  catch(Exception)
  {
    return -1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I launch this exe as part of the install process with arguments to the external executable I want to install:

```xml
<ExePackage SourceFile="$(var.MyUtility.TargetDir)MyUtility.exe"
            Compressed="yes">
  <CommandLine InstallArgument="[WixBundleOriginalSource] Data\setup.exe"/>
</ExePackage>
```

My external installer **MUST** be located in .\Data\ relative to the actual bootstrapper exe, but the arguments may be modified to point to any path. This can also be done through a Custom Action in most cases; in my case the external exe was installing SQL Server which would hang when the installation was launched through a Custom Action.